# Dataset for Swimming with Heartbeat and Motion Data

Tags: machine-learning, large-datasets, ai, data

I am currently working on my final project CS degree that involves analyzing swimming data, specifically focusing on both heartbeat and motion data. I am looking for a dataset that includes these two types of data together.

I have searched through popular data repositories like Kaggle, UCI Machine Learning Repository, PhysioNet, IEEE DataPort, and Zenodo, but haven't been able to find a suitable dataset.

Does anyone have any recommendations for where I can find a dataset that includes swimming-related data with both heartbeat and motion information? I would prefer open-access datasets for research purposes. Additionally, do you know any research papers or swimming institutions that might have published or shared such data?

Comment: You might want to clarify whether by "motion" you mean geo location data or something else like arm/leg motion.